# How to run pyinstaller from python script already converted to exe?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to run pyinstaller in python exe file in order to someone without python can use pyinstaller but no idea how to do it.

I tried import PyInstaller with other needed modules and convert this script to exe but I got error "The 'PyInstaller' distribution was not found and is required by the application". I also tried to pack PyInstaller exe file but didn't worked too. Python 3.6.5

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: A brief browse on https://www.pyinstaller.org, would reveal the (simple) steps needed.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you're describing is not possible with PyInstaller. I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6462) on GitHub, and this is what one of the developers said:

> Nope, this won't work.
>
> PyInstaller internally uses a lot of sub-processes where it is assumed that sys.executable points to a python interpreter (e.g., [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/cab6bda6df73dca0f39be33d97416cd25219f910/PyInstaller/compat.py#L513-L514)); this is not true in a frozen application, where it points to the frozen executable, which ends up in effectively endless recursion.
>
> Even if this was not a problem, the frozen application includes only a subset of python environment, so it cannot be used to freeze an arbitrary script (not to mention the issue of 3rd party packages).
>
> So whatever use case you have for this, it cannot be supported by PyInstaller.

Answer (score -1):

check the **requirements for the Pyinstaller** from this link initially
https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/requirements.html

**Then install Pyinstaller by,**

pip install pyinstaller

**To create .exe file** use this command for basically,

pyinstaller your_script.py

**To run the created .exe**

**METHOD 1**

Do double click the .exe file in your directory.

**METHOD 2**

In your cmd prompt load in to your current directory or project directory then do

: .\dist\your_script.exe

## because the create .exe files are saved in dist folder inside to the project folder with the name of your script file names only.